# I am trying to center these elements within a background image

Tags: html, css, laravel, semantic-ui

I am currently having an issue centering these elements within my background image. I want the `<p>` tag to be below the `<h1>` tag and the button below the `<p>` tag. I tried adding `<br>` tags to break them up but that doesn't seem to work. I am also using semantic so maybe some of that code is overriding what I want to do?
Any help would be appreciated!
[image]

```css
    .hero-image {
     background: url('/images/charity.jpg');
        background-position: center,top;
        background-repeat: no-repeat,no-repeat;
        background-size: cover,cover;
        height: 100%;
    
    }
    
        .hero-image:before {
        content: '';
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     right: 0;
     bottom: 0;
     left: 0;
     background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right,#759FA2,#759FA2);
     opacity: .8; 
      }
    
      .about .wrapper {
           padding: 30px 20px 0;
      }
    
    .description{
        color: #505050;
        line-height: 1.4;
    }
    
    .logo-carousel {
     padding: 10px 20px 0;
    }
    
    
    .about {
    
        background-color: #FBFAF8;
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    
    .hero-image .wrapper {
        align-items: center;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        height: 100%;
        position: relative;
    }
    
    .hero-image h1 {
        font-size: 3.125em;
        color: #fff;
        line-height: 1.2;
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    
    .hero-image p {
        color: #fff;
        line-height: 1.2;
        text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
 <section class="hero-image">
     <div class="ui container wrapper">
      <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
      <br>
      <p>consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod</p>
      <br>
      <button class="ui green button">tempor incididunt ut labore</button>
     </div>
         
    </section>
    <section class="ui container stackable logo-carousel">
     <img src="{{asset('images/zip.png')}}" alt="">
    </section>
    <section class="about">
    <div class="ui container wrapper">
     <h3 class="ui headline">Welcome to Find Kind Media!</h3>
     <p class="description">Hi, My name is Marika. I am Web Developer who has a love & passion for helping people.  
     <br>
     
    
       </p>
      <img src="{{public_path('images/charity.jpg')}}" alt="">
      </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Add flex-direction: column to .hero-image .wrapper

Comment: That works but it's not centering my elements.it's pushing the elements all the way to the top of the page

Answer (score 1):

I see that you have used ***display: -webkit-flex;***. In order for the elements to render in the way you want, all you need to do is add ***flex-direction: column;*** line to that same class. Here's your solution with this single line added.

Also I took the liberty of removing the line breaks which you had added in your html.

```css
 .hero-image {
     background: url('/images/charity.jpg');
        background-position: center,top;
        background-repeat: no-repeat,no-repeat;
        background-size: cover,cover;
        height: 100%;
    
    }
    
        .hero-image:before {
        content: '';
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     right: 0;
     bottom: 0;
     left: 0;
     background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right,#759FA2,#759FA2);
     opacity: .8; 
      }
    
      .about .wrapper {
           padding: 30px 20px 0;
      }
    
    .description{
        color: #505050;
        line-height: 1.4;
    }
    
    .logo-carousel {
     padding: 10px 20px 0;
    }    
    
    .about {
    
        background-color: #FBFAF8;
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    
    .hero-image .wrapper {
        align-items: center;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        height: 100%;
        position: relative;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    
    .hero-image h1 {
      display: block;
        font-size: 3.125em;
        color: #fff;
        line-height: 1.2;
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    
    .hero-image p {
      display: block;
        color: #fff;
        line-height: 1.2;
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    .button{
      display: block;
    }
```

```html
<section class="hero-image">
     <div class="ui container wrapper">
      <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
      <p>consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod</p>
      <button class="ui green button">tempor incididunt ut labore</button>
     </div>
         
    </section>
    <section class="ui container stackable logo-carousel">
     <img src="{{asset('images/zip.png')}}" alt="">
    </section>
    <section class="about">
    <div class="ui container wrapper">
     <h3 class="ui headline">Welcome to Find Kind Media!</h3>
     <p class="description">Hi, My name is Marika. I am Web Developer who has a love & passion for helping people.  
     <br>
     
    
       </p>
      <img src="{{public_path('images/charity.jpg')}}" alt="">
      </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

To make sure that paragraph,heading and button are displayed separately use
{display:inline;}
in div element.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to implement `flexbox` for the items with that wrapper? That's why they are going horizontal.

Adding a wrap and width to your `flexbox`'s children will solve this.

ps Don't forget your browser prefixes

```
.hero-image .wrapper {
    -webkit-box-align: center;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
            align-items: center;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.hero-image h1,
.hero image p,
.hero-image button {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Example Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/corofb0s/

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to center the `.wrapper` element within their respective parent `<section>` elements. Adding flexbox rules to the child elements won't work. Instead, you need to put the flexbox rules onto the `<section>` element instead, which will then center the child `.wrapper` divs.

For the example below, I've added a class called `.visually-centered` which will vertically and horizontally center the child `.wrapper` element.

```css
.hero-image {
  background: url('/images/charity.jpg');
  background-position: center,top;
  background-repeat: no-repeat,no-repeat;
  background-size: cover,cover;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.hero-image:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right,#759FA2,#759FA2);
  opacity: .8; 
}

.about .wrapper {
  padding: 30px 20px 0;
}

.description{
  color: #505050;
  line-height: 1.4;
}

.logo-carousel {
  padding: 10px 20px 0;
}


.about {
  background-color: #FBFAF8;
  width: 100%;
}


.hero-image .wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.hero-image h1 {
  font-size: 3.125em;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 1.2;
}


.hero-image p {
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 1.2;
}

/* New helper class to keep things DRY */
.visually-centered {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

/* Used just for the example so that it renders properly. */
.hero-image,
.about {
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<section class="hero-image visually-centered">
  <div class="ui container wrapper">
    <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
    <p>consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod</p>
    <button class="ui green button">tempor incididunt ut labore</button>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="ui container stackable logo-carousel">
  <img src="{{asset('images/zip.png')}}" alt="">
</section>

<section class="about visually-centered">
  <div class="ui container wrapper">
    <h3 class="ui headline">Welcome to Find Kind Media!</h3>
    <p class="description">Hi, My name is Marika. I am Web Developer who has a love & passion for helping people.</p>
    <img src="{{public_path('images/charity.jpg')}}" alt="">
  </div>
</section>
```